# Leaving the airport during a long layover

Tags: visas, air-travel, tickets, layovers

I have this UAE visa and my time between flights is more than 12 hours. Can I go out of airport and see the city, or do I need something else?

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: I've given your question a better title but it would help if you edited to include your nationality, what kind of visa you got, and what airport you would like to step out of.

Comment: No specific knowledge BUT you;ll need a visa, or have visa free entry status or similar at any location where you do this. A short entry is (probably) always the same as any other entry - they may provide vis free access or N day visa etc but you must comply. This MUST be on their immigration website.

Answer (score 1):

If you are traveling with Emirates, check at their transfer desk - they will arrange the visa for you. Otherwise, for 12 hour transit you can get a transit visa at the counter right before immigration, and visit the city.

However, you may not even need a visa depending on your nationality. It is best to check with the UAE immigration. Emirates provides a [handy guide](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/uae_visas.aspx) which lists those nationalities that do not need a visa or can get a visa on arrival.

From the airport, you can take the metro (light rail) or the cab. There are luggage storage lockers available at the metro station; and also at Dubai Mall.

Plan to leave quite early for your departure as traffic in Dubai can get thick in the evenings.